# QGIS ->ArcGIS Server configuration possible?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, postgresql, open-source-gis, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to connect a QGIS Desktop 1.8.0 to an ArcGIS Server 10.0 ? and of course publish services on it?.

The configuration would be like this **Quantum GIS-> ArcGIS Server 10.0 on Amazon EC2+ POstgreSQL (+PostGIS)-> web app**.

Is it possible to create a configuration like this? Do you think I could use it for networking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my understanding...

You can install all this software on Amazon machine.

Regarding connection-- You can insert ArcGIS Server WMS to QGIS (Using ADD WMS Layer)

You can not publish data from QGIS to ArcGIS Server. Its totally different architecture (open source/closed Source)

Regarding PostGIS Yes..you can install it on AMI Machine and you can connect from ArcGIS desktop to PostGIS (Add Spatial Server option in ArcCatalog)

If you want to publish data then you need to put your data in ArcMap than publish as map service (to ArcGIS Server & then create the Web application) but from Q-GIS you can not do these tasks..

I hope this will help you..let us know if you  have any questions..thanks

Comment: the answer i needed was:" You can not publish data from QGIS to ArcGIS Server". I knew it's different architecture but wanted to make sure this isn't possible. So thanks for the quick and thorough answer.