# QGIS --> ArcGIS server by WMS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, wms

I have found this post:
[QGIS ->ArcGIS Server configuration possible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41626/quantum-gis-arcgis-server-configuration-possible)
My question is more specific >>
Can I publish feature layers to ArcGIS server from QGIS using WMS?

Comment: It's the same answer: "You can not publish data from QGIS to ArcGIS Server. Its totally different architecture (open source/closed Source)"

Comment: Hmmm...I think it's a dupe of a different [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/64104/2856), though the answer is the same ("no you can't do it").

Comment: Unlike MapServer and GeoServer which allow you to configure a WMS as a data source, AFAIK this isn't possible with ArcGIS server.